# Access Replace Function

Tags: ms-access

I have the following Access query:

```
SELECT [city]
FROM [patient]
WHERE REPLACE([patient].[city],'  ',' ') LIKE 'San D*'
```

I'm relatively certain this used to work but now I get `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Anyone willing to test the sql against their own data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a null value in the column.

The solution is:

```
SELECT [city]
FROM [patient]
WHERE REPLACE(
  IIF(ISNULL([patient].[city]),'',[patient].[city])
  ,'  ',' ') LIKE 'San D*'
```

Comment: That's quite helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Is the city stored as a string? If its stored as a number (perhaps as an fkey to another table) then this would make sense as you're using string operations on it.

Edit: Note to self: stop forgetting about Null values.

Comment: @ic3b3rg Are you absolutely sure it is a string? You have looked at the table itself in design view and ensured that a look-up table has not been used? I ask, because the query works for me.

Comment: @Remou The problem was a null value in the column - I added an answer with the solution.